# maps load infinitely after restriction of user ability to pan the map

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to restrict user's ability to pan map out of a defined boundign box.

I have set two vars "initExtent" and "validExtent" (valid bounding box) for the map and on extent change I check current extent.

but map loads infinitely after extent is changed:

```
var initExtent = esri.geometry.Extent({
        "xmax":  -8550513.84 ,
        "xmin": -10751900.25,
        "ymax": 7187679.36,
        "ymin": 5720088.41,
        "spatialReference": {
            "wkid": 102100
        }
    });

    var validExtent = esri.geometry.Extent({
        "xmax":  -8350513.84 ,
        "xmin": -10951900.25,
        "ymax": 7387679.36,
        "ymin": 5520088.41,
        "spatialReference": {
            "wkid": 102100
        }
    });

    map = new Map( "map" , {    
        extent: initExtent,
        zoom : 6,
        logo: false
    });

     on(map, 'extent-change', function(evt) {
            if ( !initExtent.contains(evt.extent) ) {
                console.log('Outside bounds!');
            } else {
                console.log('Updated extent');
                validExtent = evt.extent;
            }
        });


    on(map, 'pan-end', function(evt) {
            if ( !initExtent.contains(evt.extent) ) {
                map.setExtent(validExtent);
            }
        });
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial value you are setting validExtent to isn't actually valid in that it's not contained within your initExtent.  I suspect that what might be happening is that the on pan-end is firing before the validExtent variable is set to something valid and this is causing it to infinitely loop trying to set an invalid extent, detecting its invalid and so setting it again, over and over.  Try setting the values of validExtent to be contained within the values of initExtent.

Comment: Yes, but the value you first set validExtent to isn't.  It might not be the issue, but it would be worth setting the first value of validExtent to something that is actually valid to check.  Also, what output are you getting on the console log?  this might help determine which events are being fired.  Also, I notice you aren't loading any layers in the example code - it might be worth loading at least one layer to see if that has an impact.